# Algolia filter equivalent to SQL IN for arrays?

Tags: algolia

I've got records in Algolia containing an array attribute with integer values, like :

```
{
  ...
  choice_ids: [1, 99, 100, 200]
  ...
}
```

I want to filter all records containing any value of another array. For example I search for [1, 300, 400, 600, 700], I should get the record on top because it contains 1.

Should I construct the filter with OR arguments or is there a better way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Should I construct the filter with OR arguments or is there a better way?

Yes that's the way to go.

```
index.search('....', { filters: '(choice_ids=1 OR choice_ids=99 OR choice_ids=100 OR choice_ids=200)' });
```

Comment: Still this the best way ? No other solutions ?

Comment: Yes, still the best way.

Comment: Is there a limit on total number of values we pass in filters?

Answer (score 1):

For me it wasn't working with '=' but with ':', meaning:

```
{ filters: 'choice_ids:1 OR choice_ids:99 OR choice_ids:100 OR choice_ids:200' })
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, neither of @Léo Chaz Maltrait or @redox answers worked. I had to format mine like:

```
{ filters: '(choice_ids:"1") OR (choice_ids:"99" OR (choice_ids:"100") OR (choice_ids:"200"))' })
```

I am also using `algoliasearch` npm package.